# no possibility to unzip .zip magento on the server

Tags: magento-2.1

I put the magento .zip file on the VPS server. then download unzipper.php from github and uplaod on the server. When I try to unzip magento folder then I get error.

[image]

Anyone know how to solve it ?

Comment: Looks like a permission error. Try changing permissions in the folder where the zip file is located to 777, then change them back after unzipping.

Comment: What server are you running? Linux? Commando line / Shell access?

Comment: I am using linux debian. I have given SSH permissions to the FTP user and the entire folder, unfortunately it does not work, maybe I'm doing something wrong.  - user:
chown -R myuserftp /var/www/html

-catalog:
chmod -R u+rX /var/www/html